# Good book or resource that talks about custom connectors and SharePoint search Integration?

Tags: visual-studio, crawling, bcs

Do you know any good books or resources that explains how to write your own custom connector for search crawling?

I have been reading [Professional Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2010](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-047061790X.html?cid=RSS_WROX_ALLNEW) which talks about what I want to learn but by skipping several necessarily steps to be able to follow. I need a resource that talks about the same things but in a more step by step way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a resource on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625800.aspx

And a followon article by Cory Roth on how to debug them - http://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1525610

Comment: Thanks I giving you the right answer even though I was hopping for more tips.